# How scale mesh object with hair?

Tags: particles, hair, scale

I sculpt a realistic human character and made the hair system for the size of the sculpture.
Now need append he in my animation, all objects obey the scale of the real world (doors, windows, tables ...) So I need to resize my character to 1.75m in height in my scene, but I have a **problem**, when i **resize the character the hair is messed up**.
[image]
Help me please?

Comment: Can you add a blend file to your question?  We find it easier to investigate problems if we can look at the actual file.

Comment: Did you do a particle edit?

Comment: Yes, i added hair particles and combed

Comment: I think it's very hard to make these kinds of changes after combing, since you'd have to change the hair length.  You should be able to make the whole thing a child of an empty object and scale that, though, as thibsert suggests at the end of their answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your character has an armature, resize the armature instead of resizing the mesh. The hair length should be correctly affected by the resize.

If you don't use an armature : Parent your character to an Empty, then resize the Empty.

Comment: Tried this and it didn't work :(